# jQuery Mobile text and notext button vertical alignment

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I place text buttons next to notext buttons in the header, the notext button show up slightly lower than. I've tried setting margin-top and padding-top for ui-btn-icon-notext, but that does not seem to have an effect.

[image: issue]

```
<div data-role="header" class="ui-bar">
    ...  
   <div class="ui-btn-right">
     <a href="/" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true">Sign In</a>
     <a href="/" data-icon="home-blue" data-theme="e" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why it is happening but a quick (and dirty) fix could be like this:

```
a.custom-class-name-for-no-text-buttons {
    top: -2px !important;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/GG3qE/

Comment: I tried something similar before and it didn't work, but the "!important" declaration seems to make the difference. Thanks!